# C# foreach loop works only with last item

Tags: c#, list, foreach

So I have following code in C# (XNA)

```
foreach (Target i in Target.List)
{
      //just distance calculating with pythagoras
      if (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((Tpos.X - i.pos.X), 2) + Math.Pow((Tpos.Y - i.pos.Y), 2)) <= 100)
      {
           intersect = true;
      }
      else
      {
           intersect = false;
      }
}
```

Each of these "Targets" is created like this:

```
Tower.List.Add(new Tower(Tpos));
```

The problem is that it only seems to work with the last created Target. But each of them gets drawn properly, by a similar foreach loop.

What is different?

Comment: Are you copying intersect to some collection, because if not then it is only being overwritten each time

Comment: Please explain what is your objective with this loop. Find the first Target that intersects? Search if all Targets intersects? It seems that there is a bit of confusion about how a loop works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you just want to test if your a `Target` in the list sort of intersects with variable `Tpos`.

You should initialize `intersect` with `false` before the loop, and inside the loop, just remove the `else` statement.

This way, if an element do not intersect but your `intersect` variable is already set to `true`, it will not reset it to `false`.

Also, you might want to add a `break` statement inside your `if` after you do `intersect = true`, since once you find a `Target` that intersects your `Tpos`, you don't need to test whether the rest of the data do intersect:

```
foreach (Target i in Target.List)
{
      //just distance calculating with pythagoras
      if (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((Tpos.X - i.pos.X), 2) + Math.Pow((Tpos.Y - i.pos.Y), 2)) <= 100)
      {
           intersect = true;
           break;
      }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated hint: it's expensive to calculate a Sqrt, do you see how you can eliminate it and use 10000 instead of 100?

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but it may have something to do with the fact that you're only outputting to one variable, so it gets over written by each loop.

i.e.

`intersect = true;`
`intersect = false;`

therefore intersect = false.

**EDIT:** Try writing to a variable in a list. That way you can have multiple copies of the same variable.

Comment: Steve beat me to it :)